# Analysis of a jazz chord progression

Tags: harmony, chord-theory, chord-progressions, analysis, functional-harmony

Can you please explain the role of that Em7b5 in the following jazz progression in terms of functional harmony?

| **Cm7** | **Em7b5** | **Bbmaj7** | **G7** |

Comment: What happens after the `G7`? In comments below, you say the progression loops. Is that all just these four chord repeating, or does it go somewhere else?

Comment: A melody laid over these chords could make a world of difference in deciding what's a good analysis. Or generally, hearing the progression in a larger context. What about the progression is "jazz"? To me there's nothing that says it has to be jazz in any way. These are quite commonly used chords that could occur in many genres.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica - Personally, I took the question's mentioning that the chord progression is "jazz" to be permission to use some non-common practice period harmony conventions (e.g. tritone substitution) when analyzing that progression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even in tonal music every chord does *not* need to have a functional role.

Beside the possibility of mixing tonal and non-functional harmony, the obvious case would be a *passing chord*.

```
| Cm7 | Em7b5 | Bbmaj7 | G7 |
```

In that progression `Cm7` and `Bbmaj7` combine to give all tones for `Bb` major, the `G7` could also be a clear secondary dominant to the `Cm7`. Without any other details about what this music does, it set's up a very clear possibility for `Bb` major as the tonic. Nominally it could be...

```
|     Cm7 | Em7b5 | Bbmaj7 | G7    |
| Bb: ii7 | p.c.  | IM7    | V7/ii |
```

...I say 'nominally' because you don't have a dominant for `Bb`.

You could add the dominant with something like this...

```
|     Cm7 | Em7b5 | Bbmaj7 | G7    | Cm7 | F7 | Bbmaj7
| Bb: ii7 | p.c.  | IM7    | V7/ii | ii7 | V7 | IM7
```

...I only add the dominant, because your question is posed in terms of *functional* harmony, and I wanted to complete the picture how what you already have could be emphatically functioning in `Bb`. Of course harmony does not need to be functional, but to the extent that it is, the dominant is *critical* for establishing tonality. Adding a dominant (to a tonic, not a secondary dominant) makes the functions clear.

`p.c.` above means passing chord.

> ...in terms of functional harmony?

In functional harmony, secondary functions, need to be backed up with some kind of analysis that the purported secondary function is *actually fulfilled*.

If `Em7b5` is supposed to be either `viiø7` - or the theoretical incomplete `V9` in `F` major, or `iiø7` in `D` minor, *something* of either function needs to actually be in the music. The next *actual* chord is `Bbmaj7`, which is `IVmaj7` in `F` major or `bVImaj7` in `D` minor.

So, that would give us a dominant to subdominant in `F` major or subdominant to submediant in `D` minor. In terms of *functional* harmony, both are dubious. At best you might call the first some sort of deceptive move and the second pre-dominant movement that never actually moves to it's related dominant.

I think your four chords hint at the possibility of `Bb` major, but the `Em7b5` doesn't seem to have a function to that tonic or convincingly to another. That is *not* a problem. You can voice the chords so that `Em7b5` connects `Cm7` to `Bbmaj7` in all step-wise motion and consider it a passing chord.

Your function does not fall right into clear tonal function. It's ambiguous. That's why every answer so far gives you completely different analysis. Calling it ambiguous isn't a *diagnosis*, it's just a *description*. Unless your purpose is to revise it for clear function, there's nothing to "fix." Although, if you want to embrace ambiguous, non-functional harmony, I'd say don't get hung up on functional analysis. Why do functional analysis if you don't care about function harmony? Look to other musical elements to assess what you're doing.

---

EDIT to elaborate on comments:

To understand functional harmony you need to understand dominant harmony and to understand dominant harmony you need to understand how the leading tone and subdominant work. I like to do that in solfege and will use that below.

Dominant function at its essence is leading tone `TI` moving to *up* tonic `DO` and subdominant `FA` moving *down* to mediant `MI`. `TI` and `FA` are the tones that define a dominant chord. Labeled as chord tones `TI` and `FA` are respectively the *major third* and *minor seventh* of a dominant chord. This is true in the "classical" style and jazz too.

When tones are altered from diatonic they tend to move in the direction of the alteration. So, for example a tone that is altered by raising it tends to move up a step as its next move. In practical, functional terms, this means raised tones often become new leading tones and lowered tones often act as new subdominants and involve either a modulation or a tonicization. If an altered tone does not act in that *functional* way, it may be reasonable to then consider the altered tone a chromatic passing tone.

The term *passing* is applied to a tone or tones that do not belong to a proper chord. In the nomenclature of non-chord tones *passing* is applied when the case is specifically all the tones involved moving by step in the same direction. Example, in a `C` major chord, with melodic motion of `C D E` the `D` does not belong to the `C` major chord, but "passes" between chord tones `C` and `E` with the whole passage being steps in the same direction.

More than one tone could be involved with a passing motion. The commonest example is the *passing 6/4 chord*. Example, in `C: I6 V6/4 I` the `V6/4` is considered dissonant, an "improper" chord, with the impropriety being the `D` in the bass. If the voice leading is such that the bass part is `E D C` the then `D` is a passing tone between the chords tones `E` of `I6` and `C` of `I`, and the whole chord is referred to as a *passing chord.*

"Passing" can be applied generally to *anything*, even entire passages of harmony, that are regarded as unessential to the principle harmonic structure.

Back to the functional analysis.

In `Bb` major we have this essential functional movement of the subdominant...

[image]

In my analysis of `Bb` major, and the other answers of `C` minor, either key treats the `Eb` as a *diatonic* tone, therefore the `E` natural of the second chord is an *altered* tone. With the tendency of raised altered tones to move up that results in `E` natural becoming a new leading tone tonicizing the dominant...

[image]

...*tonicizing* means that the tone `F` which is regarded as the dominant scale degree, `SOL`, in `Bb` changes to the tonic scale degree, `DO`, in `F`. Temporary shifting of the tonic like this is normal in functional harmony.

Even in the case of analyzing the progression in `C` minor, the alteration of of `Eb` to `E` natural would still tend to move up to `F`, where the `E` natural again becomes a leading tone, but this time to the subdominant.

[image]

...that `E` natural could be emphatically harmonized with dominant harmony in a `C7` chord `Cm: V7/iv`.

I'll continue looking at it in `Bb` major.

Let's now look at how you could harmonize `E` in `Bb` major, *in functional terms*, either as unaltered `Eb` or altered `E` natural.

Unaltered `Eb` is the subdominant `FA` which in a dominant chord will move down to the mediant `MI` of a tonic chord...

[image]

Altered `E` natural acting in a *functional* way is the new leading tone `TI` which in a dominant chord will move up to the tonic `DO` of a new tonicized chord...

[image]

Those two examples are just the basic functional expectation of `Eb` and `E` natural in `Bb`.

Your actual progression does something else. The `E` natural is the *root* of a half diminished chord.

It is possible to regard that half diminished chord as an incomplete `C9` chord where the `E` natural is the chord's third. But, in that case the tonic it implies is `F`.

However, the next chord is not a `F` chord. It's a `Bb` chord. You could call it a *retrogression* or a *deceptive* progression, but suffice to say *it is not progressing in the conventional functional way.* As stated before we can then regard the `E` natural as *not* a functional tone of a dominant chord, but as a *chromatic passing tone.*

If we voice the whole chord so that all tones are moving in smooth voice leading step, the entire chord can be regarded as a *passing chord*.

[image]

Comment: This makes it seem that the purpose of functional harmony is to correctly label things in an exam. I'd like to expand its practical use to see unfulfilled patterns, what _could_ have happened and what potential expectations were created. Like, seeing that inserting an F7 between Em7b5 and Bbmaj7 would fill a gap. This might give potential patterns to use when writing an arrangement or solo or something.

Comment: @michael curtis what do you exactly mean for passing chords?

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica, I don't know, I've never taken an exam to do harmonic analysis. The practical purpose of harmonic analysis is to identify chords in a key. Personally, I only do that when something stands out as unusual. In this question, the only thing analysis tells me is there isn't a clear case for identifying a tonic, which is why my answer is _nominally_ the progression is in Bb. Why the OP wants to analyze, what will they do with the info: I don't know.

Comment: @LeoAn, I added some more to my answer. Not sure if it answers your question. Do you know the basic definition of passing motion?

Comment: I tried to say, don't get too hung up on the OP's using the word "functional" - he probably just meant all possible kinds of ways to handle the chord, functional or whatever. Which, I guess, the answer now does, with staff notation examples and all. I'd add a couple more things: compare the sound of the half-diminished Em7-5 with (1) fully diminished Edim7, and (2) Eb maj7. And (3) if you do the Bb maj7 as Bb _maj9_ i.e. Dm7/Bb. How about: Em7-5, Eb maj7, Eb dim7 (i.e. rootless F7b9), Bb maj9. Or: Em7-5, Edim7, Eb dim7, Bb9. Just to see what the progression _could be_ with a few modifications.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica. I'm not hung up on anything. _Functional harmony_ means something and it's not "all possible ways to handle a chord." That would render the term meaningless.

Answer (score 3):

I have to admit that it's easier for me to think of the Em7♭5 as a voice leading construct, as Cm7 - Em7♭5 only requires shifting the Cm7's C and E♭ one step each and leaving its G and B♭ as is, and Em7♭5 - B♭maj7 only requires shifting the Em7♭5's E and G one step each and leaving its B♭ and D as is.

With that being said, there are at least two ways of trying to fit that Em7♭5 into functional harmony.

Aaron's answer partially alludes to Em7♭5 being a **tritone substitution of V7/iv** or a **rootless version of V9/iv**. Tritone substitution involves keeping a tritone in the chord you want to modify, changing at least one other note, and expecting the tritone to resolve the same way (barring enharmonic re-spellings) in both chords.

We can also think of Em7♭5 as **(♮)viø7/v**, so Cm7 - Em7♭5 - B♭maj7 - G7 can be interpreted as i7 - (♮)viø7/v - III7/v = VII7 - V7.

Comment: This is not a progression that has meaning in functional terms. Naming the chords, even applying RNA is fine, but vi - III - I (all "/V") isn't a functional progression. I think you were closer to the mark in calling it a voice-leading progression. Jazz certainly feels no compulsion to adhere to common-practice era rules of harmony, but it often follows more-or-less smooth voice-leading.

Answer (score 2):

The Em7b5 here is functioning as a substitute for C9 — that is, it's as though the music shifted from C minor to C major. The C is established as the tonic by the first chord, so the ear will retain it and hear the E chord in that context. Thus in functional harmony terms, the progression would be `i | I | VII | V` .

```
(Cm9) (C9)
Cm7   Eb7b5

(D)   D
Bb    Bb
G     G
Eb    E
C     (C)
```

A similar relationship — an implied minor-to-major shift — exists between the following two chords. Consider that BbM7 contains the upper notes of Gm9.

```
(Gm9) (G9)
BbM7  G7

A     (A)
F     F
D     D
Bb    B
(G)   G
```

In that light, the entire progression can be viewed as:

`i | I | v | V` or `i9 | I9 | v9 | V9`

Comment: It's interesting that on this forum, in other questions, excepting a minor blues, which this is not, it's been noted that a minor tonic would not be a minor seventh chord. That would make this minor `i` seem doubtful.

Comment: This is what I was about to write! :)  The pattern that is here Cm7, Em7b5 appears often as a _voicing_, whether or not we declare it a "passing chord". Another possibility for the next harmony would be some sort of F (for which that seeming E-chord is a rootless C, dominant 7), etc. But the ambiguity of that E-chord may be useful in getting to the Bb... :)

Answer (score 2):

| Cm7 | Em7b5 | Bbmaj7 | G7 |

The Em7b5 works as a secondary dominant *in the sense that it makes you expect an F something chord*, the E note sounds like a leading tone heading to F. But instead of an F based chord, the progression gives you a Bb chord. So a secondary dominant function doesn't really get fulfilled, the desire and wanting is interrupted. But when reasoning about what's happening in the progression, it's good to know the "what *could* have happened" and what expectations the chords created in your mind along the way.

Do you feel that the home chord is C minor, or maybe G minor? Or Bb major? What's the key in your opinion? To me the Bb being a maj7 makes it sound like it's more in Gm or Bb than in Cm.

You could respell the Em7b5 as C9/E. Which could be simplified as C7/E. Or even just C/E. Or just a plain E note without anything else, given this context.

To try and feel how the secondary dominant would have worked, had there been the F chord. How would this sound like to you:

| Cm7 | C9/E | F7 | Bbmaj7 |

Now you're in Bb major. Or I am at least, YMMV.

But back to the original progression, the G7 could be a secondary dominant going back to Cm7, if you think the real key is Gm or Bb. Or if you feel the real key is Cm, then the G7 would be Cm's dominant. But nevertheless, the Em7b5 still works as a potential secondary dominant in all interpretations, in the sense of creating expectations.

Comment: How would `Em7b5` actually work as a secondary dominant if the key is `Bb` or `Gm`? It doesn't do anything to actually function that way.

Comment: If dominant seventh chord doesn't actually do anything to _function_ as a `V` there is no justification for calling it a `V`. Non-function dominant seventh chords are a thing.

Comment: What discussion? It does not necessarily need to be an `F` chord, and I have _never_ said that kind of thing before. It just needs to do _something_ to justify the claim. Putting key labels with RNA will make a _big_ difference instead of sprinkling Roman numerals into comments.

Comment: Oh, I just remember talking about this many times before, sorry. This may seem like an inappropriate analogy, but it's justifiable to call a dance sexy, even though it doesn't eventually lead to intercourse. But the mechanisms are there all the same. In a way the whole art of music-making is about creating feelings, don't you agree? You hint about something, reveal a bit ... but then don't give it to the listener. Maybe it's an unorthodox way of looking at music. I tried to edit the answer to remove the claim about actually _being_ a secondary dominant, from all points of view at least.

Comment: The OP is asking something specific _functional_ analysis. Just write a Roman numeral analysis for the whole progression. First let an analysis do the talking, then elaborate with some discussion.

Comment: Usually, the literal question asks for something that's a bit ill-adviced and cannot explain the situation. I'm trying to answer the real problem that the OP couldn't ask. Functional harmony in its pure form is quite a simplistic model, and if things like unfulfulled expectations aren't allowed, then it's hard to "analyse" real world pieces.

Comment: But that doesn't seem to be the case in this question. It all reads very straight forward.

Comment: Many times, a question clearly demands a specific type of answer, even if it's based on a misconception or lack of experience. StackExchange or StackOverflow was originally created to displace an annoying computer and programming Q&A site called "experts-exchange". To be a "better experts-exchange". So, the format was in a way made for experts to help other experts. But on many SE sites, the posters behind the questions are _not_ experts! And this creates a problem, because the site format kind of assumes that the question's (mis-informed) premises must be followed ... My opinion only though.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis How does the answer look now after my edits? I'm trying to say, it sounds like a secondary dominant sort of motion is being set up, but then cancelled at the last minute. Saying that it's "non-functional" or "passing chord" doesn't really say anything about what the chord _does_. It does do _something_, and I feel that I could describe what that something is. I try at least.

Comment: Functional analysis: I'm expecting Roman numerals or those German labels. "Passing chord" is not some contrivance of mine. It's a standard theory term. I does say something: it means it is not an essential part of the functional harmony, it's something passing in between the essential harmonic elements.

Comment: I don't want to keep extending this, but one thing should be made clear: analyzing the expressiveness of music is not _functional harmonic analysis_. A progression like `I IV V` in terms of expression could be an upbeat boogie, or a poignantly bittersweet melody, or anything in between. None of that changes the harmonic analysis of `I IV V`

Answer (score 0):

Em7♭5 is a re-voicing of Gm6. Gm is the relative minor of B♭ major. So another slant on the sequence could be ii7 > vi6 > I▵ > V/ii. Does the pattern loop at that point, or does it develop further? Right now, more information would elicit a clearer answer.

Comment: The pattern loop

Comment: Just trying to keep this reasonably _functional_ `vi7` would be `Gm7` not `Gm6`, the `E` natural of `Gm6` would be a `#4` in `Bb`. For a chord that would be _implying_ a tonality that's reaching pretty far.

Answer (score -1):

I'd actually take a completely different take than the other answers here. The sequence

Cm7 | Em7b5 | BbMaj7 | G7

Is likely a root of Eb progression. Cm7 is VI, BbMaj7 is V (though Maj7 chords are frequently IV) and Em7b5 is likely a tritone substitution for BbMaj7. A more clear example is the a `II V I` in the key of Eb, with Cm7 serving as a substitute of Fm7. A more commonly extended version of `II V I` is `III VI II V I`. Keeping this assumption in mind, Em7b5 is substitute for II (which is a flat II in key of Eb). It's difficult to ascertain which is the intention without looking at the key the melody is playing in.

Since the question asked about the Em7b5, the G7 was mostly ignored but I doubt that will change the options here. If the 4 chord progression is repeated as written above, then it's clearly `III VI II V (I)` without resolving the root if the composer wanted to make some artistic substitutions (flat II substituting II, dominant III replacing III, Maj7 replacing dominant on V) but it's difficult to give a decisive answer without the key or surrounding chords. But the answer fundamentally boils down to it being an embellishment; a substitution for an otherwise standard chord.

After thinking about it for a while, there is another common progression that this does follow (Rock/Alternative/Fusion progression) `VI IV V III`. The entire explanation above is the same (same key and same replacements for the standard chords) but the Em7b5 is a substitution for IV. This explanation doesn't require much of an intuitive leap as `(III) VI II V` repeated as the bar starts on the correct measure instead of one measure behind. So now it will be `VI bIIm7b5 VMaj7 III7, with bIIm7b5 substituting IV, VMaj7 substituting the common V7 and III7 substituting the common IIIm7.

Comment: Are saying it is this: `Eb: vi7 | bII7b5 | Vmaj7 | V7/vi`?

Comment: @MichaelCurtis The last is III (G is III of Eb). I frequently do tritone substitutions for V especially (e.g. Fm7 Bb7/Bb7b5 EbMaj7). A dominant with a flat 5th is the chord as it's tritone dominant with a flat 5th, that is to say that Bb7b5 is indistinguishable from E7b5. So a Em7b5 is not how I would have made the substitution but it's the same form regardless.

Comment: You say that "Em7b5 is likely a tritone substitution for BbMaj7" - where is the tritone in a BbMaj7 chord? I'm getting Bb-D-F-A here, with no tritone.

Comment: @Dekkadeci that's not how chord substitution works, it has nothing to do with the notes in the chord your substituting.